# validity of a PDFfunction .

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

For  z∈R , define the following two functions:

$f_1(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp \left(-\frac{\max (1,z^2)}{2}\right)$

$f_2(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp \left(-\frac{\min (1,z^2)}{2}\right).$

i want to know if any of the functions is a valid PDF or can be if multiplied by a non negative constant c .

the way i see it is that the first one is a valid PDF if multiplied by constant.

but i'm still confused about the second one ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp \left(-\frac{\min (1,z^2)}{2}\right) \, dz = \int_1^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\exp \left(-\frac1{2}\right) \, dz=\infty$$

Hence, it can't be multiplied by a positive constant and form a pdf.

Comment: and my answer to the first one ?

Comment: I thought you already know the answer to that isn't it? If you integrate it over the real number you get a finite positive number isn't it?

Comment: Okai thanks , that’s reasonable I didn’t see that i should ignore the min and max from the limits of my integrals